# empty sql server database slow backup

Tags: sql-server, performance, backup

I have a SQL Server 2012 database, using filestream, which I have backed up. The backup took 24 hours and produced a 300gb file. I now want a backup of just the schema. So I truncated all the tables, and started the backup again. It is taking hours and has not yet reached 10%. I have checked the filestream folder and it is empty. The machine has 8gb of ram, and SQL is using 5gb of it. The database is in Simple recovery mode. Why would the backup still be slow now it is empty?

Comment: Did you perform a shrink after you truncated the tables?